# phpmyadmin deletes backslash and hyphen, but I don't want

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, store

I want to store some data on my phpmyadmin database. But phpmyadmin delete backslashes and hyphens in my link or text. How can i fix it ? I am using utf8_general_ci in tables.

For example this is the link I want to record

```
http://hurriyetemlak.cubecdn.net/image.ashx?type=4&image=Images\6\7\8\5\8\5\3\2\0e221cda-8822-4459-be59-0b8047227e2c.jpg
```

And here is result

```
http://hurriyetemlak.cubecdn.net/image.ashx?type=4&image=Images67858532e221cda-8822-4459-be59-0b8047227e2c.jpg
```

In this example, phpmyadmin delete backslashes after **"..image=Images"**.
And here, delete a zero before **"e221cda..."**

Also, I want to store an id number like this "**21865-3536**", but phpmyadmin convert this number to "**21865**". Why is this happening ?

Comment: Backslashes in URLs are not legal. You have to encode them.

Comment: Yes it is not legal, but I think the coder make this for anyone can't get images link like me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin *per se* but with MySQL's defaulting to considering backslashes as the escaping character.

Two solutions: either,

1. escape the backslashes in all your input (i.e. change them to `\\`)

or,

2. temporary change the [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) with :

   SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';